# PHP Random Numbers

Tags: php, random, numbers

i need to print out numbers 1-100 in a random order.  the print statement should be:

echo 'h{'.$num.'}';

what is the shortest code to do this?

Comment: Don't get caught up on how short your code is. While it should be as concise as possible, it should not be your first priority.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest way is to use [shuffle](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) with an array containing the 100 numbers

e.g.

```
$sequence = range(1, 100);
shuffle($sequence);
foreach ($sequence as $num) {
    echo 'h{'.$num.'}';
}
```

Also see the [range](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) function

**EDIT**

I thought I might add a little on what shuffle does. Although php.net doesn't explicitly say so, it is likely based on the modern version of the [Fisher-Yates shuffle algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher-Yates_shuffle). For a video demonstration of how it works, see http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ckh2DJrP7F4. Also see this excellent [flash](http://yamasv.blog92.fc2.com/blog-entry-116.html) demonstration

The shuffle algorithm essentially works like this:

1. For a given set of elements A1 to AN, and n = N;
2. Randomly select an element Ak between A1 and An inclusive
3. Swap Ak and An
4. Set n = n - 1
5. Repeat from step 2

Hope that helps.

Comment: A shorter way to say the same thing would be:
foreach (shuffle(range(1,100)) as $num) echo 'h{'.$num.'}';

Comment: @garethm: No it wouldn't, since `shuffle` does not return the array.

Answer (score 3):

See the example for [`shuffle()`](http://php.net/shuffle):

```
$numbers = range(1, 20);
shuffle($numbers);
foreach ($numbers as $number) {
    echo "$number ";
}
```

Comment: I was just copy'n'pasting from the manual. I'm leaving the customizations to the OP.

Comment: So he can fix the `echo` statement, too? ;-)

Comment: Yes he can. I think it's more important to convey the idea than copy'n'pastable solutions.

Comment: +1 for answering first and correctly. @pavium What is the point of giving people their entire programs? It's more important that the OP understands *what* is happening, and then applies it to his situation.